# Creating an External Constructor for the Natural log of the Volume of a Cube

Tags: julia

I am taking a Julia class and I am am trying to create a method to calculate the natural log of a user defined type.

I have created a parameterized type MyCube

```
type MyCube{T}
    h::T
    w::T
    l::T
end
```

and I have created 2 instances of this type and i defined them as Float64 hoping this would resolve the issue, but it didnt

```
cube1 = MyCube{Float64}(2,3,2)
cube2 = MyCube{Float64}(4,3,2)
```

Now trying to define the method

```
import Base.log
log(u::MyCube) = MyCube(log(u.h * u.w * u.l))
log(cube1)
```

and when I try to run the run the method on the instance of the type cube1

```
log(cube1)
```

I get the following error

```
LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{MyCube{T}}, ::Float64)
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor MyCube{T}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  MyCube{T}(::T, !Matched::T, !Matched::T)
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert{T}(::Type{T}, !Matched::T)
while loading In[33], in expression starting on line 2

 in log at In[32]:2
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Note that the function log is not a constructor, since it does not create a new object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`log(u::MyCube) = MyCube(log(u.h * u.w * u.l))`

Here you are you are trying to call a function (the type constructor for `MyCube`) on your `cube1`.

Just `log(u::MyCube) = log(u.h * u.w * u.l)`

Will add a new method for `log` to dispatch on your type MyCube!

Comment: beat me by less than a minute twice this week

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
log(u::MyCube) = log(u.h * u.w * u.l)
```

Comment: thanks!, I knew it was something silly, but couldn't figure it out. That fixed it